# Invoke non void functions with performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading

As the title of my question said .. I'm try to call a non-void function with `performSelectorOnMainThread` .. my function return `UIImage` , when I call it like this:

```
UImage *img = [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(captureScreen:) withObject:webView waitUntilDone:YES];
```

it gives me an error that I have incompatible assigning type , also I try to cast it like this

```
UImage *img = (UIImage*)[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(captureScreen:) withObject:webView waitUntilDone:YES];
```

and I got  *Semantic Issue: Operand of type 'void' where arithmetic or pointer type is required*

I know that I can call it as normal , but Im trying some multithreading stuff and need it to invoke like this .. so how I can prevent this error please?

**Edit :**

I try to use GCD inside this function (captureScreen) its keep making Exc_bad_access on the "viewToCapture" .. so I decide to call the parent function inside the GCD block

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [self captureScreenDelayed:pageView];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    });
});
```

and "*captureScreenDelayed*:" is as follow

```
- (void) captureScreenDelayed:(EpubPageViewController*)pageView
{
    if(!pageView)
        pageView = [self currentPageView];

    if(pageView.pageImageView)
        pageView.pageImageView.image = (UIImage*)[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(captureScreen:) withObject:webView waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

and the *captureScreen* :

```
-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewToCapture.bounds.size, viewToCapture.opaque, 0.0);
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

to be honest Im not sure if this the correct way to get the image in separated thread... I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you have to remember here is that the method that you're *actually* calling is `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` which has a `(void)` return type. Thus, you can't get the result of the performed selector returned through this method. If you need to do this type of multithreading, you should check out the [concurrency programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091) and, in particular, [grand central dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: Im using the GCD .. to understand my problem please check my edit.

Comment: I hate to say it, but what you're doing here is actually pretty dangerous. According to the documentation, `UIKit` objects should really only be accessed on the main thread (especially `UIResponder` objects, of which `UIImageView` is a subclass). http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006955-CH1-SW2

Comment: so if you were on my side .. what would yo do ? since capturing the image is necessary to execute in another thread or i will have a dangerous problem in my app UI :)

Comment: well, what are you trying to accomplish? what issues are you running into as a result of simply capturing the image on the main thread and avoiding multithreading altogether?

Comment: when I render the pages .. I have a delay in the page transition because the app isn't finish the capture .. this is the issue.

Comment: do you have to render the screen shot at the same time as the page transition?

Comment: yes .. im using pageViewController , and the only way to get the previous and next pages is to capture the webView which load the book content inside it.

Comment: so you have a page view controller that is displaying webviews? why not cache the web content for the previous and next pages when the current page loads so that it's ready when the user flips the page?

Comment: the content could be change at anytime , since the user can change the font size and type , search for text , adding note bookmark and many other things .. it will useful for me to do it in your way.

Comment: sorry, but i still don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish here. if the content can change "at any time", why would you want to store the content as static images? it seems like the question you need to be asking is about storing and retrieving content? or maybe i'm just not understanding your scenario

Comment: im not storing a static images .. in the time the user render the page I capture the webView.. in the moment I can get the content with the user settings because he change it through a menu appear just in case he tap on the current reading page.. Im sorry I can't describe all my app functionality here .. lets take as general case that you want to deal with multithreading and in same time there is UI changes need to be done.

Comment: bottom line: you can't. changes to the UI must be called on the main thread.

Comment: ok .. i will try my chance. thank you. and i will accept your answer then.

Answer (score 4):

`performSelectorOnMainThread:...` does not have a return value.   You'll need to find some other mechanism to get the image back.  One simple way, that will work in this case because you are waiting for the selector to  complete, would be to pass an NSMutableArray as your object and add the image to it in the main thread e.g.

```
NSMutableArray* parameterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[parameterArray addObject: webView];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(captureScreen:) withObject:parameterArray waitUntilDone:YES];
if ([parameterArray count > 1)
{
    UIImage* img = [webView objectAtIndex: 1];
}
else
{ 
// error
}
```

And `captureScreen:` would look something like

```
-(void) captureScreen: (NSMutableArray*) parameterArray
{
    UIView* webView = [parameterArray objectAtIndex: 0];
    // capture the screen
    [parameterArray addObject: capturedImage];
}
```

Comment: @Malek_Jundi:  it doesn't matter if you are using GCD.  fundamentally `-performSelector:` does not have a return value.  You *have* to use a different method to get the image back.

Comment: yeah i got this point , but I'm now stuck in other problem you can check the edit and comments and give some advice about how can I do it. thanks.

Comment: I tried your solution its not working .. EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION !