# Need to capture screen without delay

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

So guys I'm using this function to take a picture of the `UIWebView` which loading an e-book and display it while the user render the pages

```
-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewToCapture.bounds.size, viewToCapture.opaque, 0.0);
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

but the problem there is a delay (0.5 second) happened to get the image .. when i test in the time profiler the instruments point to this line  `[viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];` as the one which causing the delay .. so any advice , suggestion how could I come over this delay.

Thanks in advanced.

Notes :
1.Im using UIPageController for the book effect.

2.to check what I have tried please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10399235/705559)

Answer (score 1):

The best way of solving this is to use delegates. Meaning that if you tell a delegate method to make the image, it can do it in the background and tell your view "Hey, now I got you an image for XXX" (depending on how you implement it. 
This way you can load your view with the e-books in it and just show a loader in the middle of the book with a default background. When the image is done, you update the view for the book with the correct image and remove the loader.
Much like how Apple's iBooks and any other good application does.

Example from one of my own projects (adapted to your need, yet for use in UITableViewController):
**BookDelegate.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Book;

@protocol BookDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)didRecieveImageForBook:(NSString*)imagePath indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

@end
```

**Book.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BookDelegate.h"

@interface Book : NSOperation <NSObject>
{   
    id <BookDelegate> delegate;
    SEL didRecieveImageForBookSelector;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id delegate;
@property (assign) SEL didRecieveImageForBookSelector;

- (NSString*)getBookImageForBookId:(int)BookId externalRefference:(NSString*)url indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
- (id)delegate;

// Delegate methods
- (void)didRecieveImageForBook:(NSString*)imagePath indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

@end
```

**Book.m**

```
#import "Book.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation Book

static char kAssociationKey;

@synthesize didRecieveImageForBookSelector;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [self setDidRecieveImageForBookSelector:@selector(didRecieveImageForBook:indexPath:)];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark The default delegate functions

- (void)didRecieveImageForBook:(NSString*)imagePath indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"********************************************************");
    NSLog(@"*** PLEASE IMPLEMENT THE FOLLOWING DELEGATE FUNCTION ***");
    NSLog(@"***       didRecieveImageForBook:indexPath:       ***");
    NSLog(@"********************************************************");
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Function for fechting images

// This method is not adapted to what YOU need, but left my code here in case it might help you out.
- (NSString*)getBookImageForBookId:(int)bookId externalRefference:(NSString*)url indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{    
    NSString *ext = [[url lastPathComponent] pathExtension];

    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *imagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.%@", APP_BookIMAGEPEFIX, BookId, ext]];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath];

    if (fileExists)
    {
        return imagePath;
    }
    else {
        NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:theUrl];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(BookImageFetched:)];
        [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(processFailed:)];
        [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
        [request setDownloadDestinationPath:imagePath];
        [request setDelegate:self];

        [request startAsynchronous];

        objc_setAssociatedObject(request, &kAssociationKey, indexPath, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

        return @"";
    }
}

- (void)BookImageFetched:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = objc_getAssociatedObject(request, &kAssociationKey);
    NSString *imagePath = request.downloadDestinationPath;

    [[self delegate] performSelector:self.didRecieveImageForBookSelector withObject:imagePath withObject:indexPath];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark delegate functions

- (id)delegate
{
        return delegate;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id)newDelegate
{
        delegate = newDelegate;
}

#pragma mark -

@end
```

Comment: so in other words you are suggest to capture all the book pages as images and store in the memory ?!

Comment: Thats one way to do it. In one of my projects I downloaded PNG images for TV Channels which I saved locally. I checked wether there was a local image and if there was I returned it directly, otherwise I returned and empty string and let the delegate method tell my UITableView that there is a new image availale and that it belongs to a certain rowAtIndexPath. Then I just updated that cell with the new image.

Comment: ok I see .. but in my case I'm loading a chapter (html file) and paginate it using js function so I'm already have the content .. what I need to capture the next/previous pages at the moment the user render the page .. my function works well but I hate that delay , your solution will not solve the delay at all

Comment: No, but it will make the delay user friendly. Since your application doesn't lock itself your user can do whatever he/she wants, e.g. leave that page and never look at the next or prev page, hence the delay should not be that important anymore. right? Also, if you have rendered the HTML before and saved the image to file than my solution will quickly fetch it and show it, instead of re-rendering it... thus having no delay. (yet that code is not included in my answer, only the idea of how to do it).

Comment: thats right .. but the pages is not static .. the user may change the font size, type .. adding note, highlight or bookmark all these will need new images .. so its better to take the screen immediately not to fetch it before , don't you know faster way the capture the screen than the function I used ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I still don't see the issue. When you change the content show a loader for the time the user has to wait, update the image, and hide the loader. As long as the user understands that his/her action recuired a process to complete he/she will understand it. For the loader you could otherwise use MBProgressHUD.

Comment: However, if those are your requirements, having a < 0.5 sec response, then who am I to question it? I doubt however you will find a 0.0 one, my guess is you will always have a delay thus you *should* have a UI that informs the user on the delay thus it *should* be asynchronous thus you *should* use e.g. delegates.

Answer (score 1):

You could use GCD - I noticed a a step missing from the GCD in the link you gave. This is what I use to asynchronously get an image and notify when its ready and it works fine:

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrent = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(concurrent, ^{
        __block UIImage *image = nil;
        dispatch_sync(concurrent, ^{
            //put code to grab image here
        });
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //this gets called when the above is finshed
            //you should also check if the image is nil or not
        });
    });
```

hope it helps

for the record - I use this for taking UIView snapshots and always try to put my target inside a parentview even if it is temporarily - it seems to speed it up.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

not sure if it helps or if you are using the same approach. I hope you solve this soon :)

Comment: unfortunately this don't solve the delay , it will show white pages (nil images) !

Comment: ahh so you want like... instant instant image taking... depending on what device you are using and how complex the image is it might take half a second. The GCD thing I posted was assuming you were not displaying the image instantly sorry.